# How can a beginner remove an actor from footage?

Tags: video-editor, software-recommendation

I want to edit this [montage of James Bond Intros](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkNeQdLg6Nc). What I want is remove the real james bond, as a beginner what will you suggest a good video editor for this kind of situation?

Comment: Okay, so what is it that you would like to achieve, would you like to replace the subject, or do you simply just want to omit him from the shot?

Answer (score 1):

All of these seem to be simple circle mattes, you just need an editing system that allows you to generate a circle mask that has an animatable position.

You will need 3 pieces of media:
1- the original footage
2- the new actor to go in the circle (or a neutral shot)
3- the moving circle mask

You will need to animate the circle to follow the original circle, then use the circle mask to reveal the new footage in the hole.

I can recommend using the Open Software "Blender", it has a Video editor called the VSE and a system of user defined masks that you can animate with.

Answer (score 0):

Imageneer systems,  Mocha Pro is about as easy as it gets.
[See this example/tutorial](http://www.imagineersystems.com/videos/removing-a-microphone-with-mocha-pro-and-adobe-photoshop/?back=http://www.imagineersystems.com/video/page/2/?dd=dateNew&orderby=date&order=DESC)
But it is far from simple!

There are versions of Mocha available for After Effects and Hitfilm as well. I'm not sure If they are capable of doing this.